# How to pass a square wave through transfer function in MATLAB?

Tags: passive-networks, matlab, band-pass

I am currently trying to create a band stop filter which attenuates frequencies between 2000Hz and 8000Hz. I have got the transfer function but now I am struggling to find the documentation on how to pass a square wave of 6000Hz and another sqaure wave of 20 000Hz to test the filter. I am doing this on MATLAB or Octave so any help will be appreciated. Should I be using the step function to get the frequency response graph?

Comment: Have you tried 'gensig'?

Comment: What band pass and band stop levels do you need? expect ?+/-1kHz and if breakpoints are -3dB.

Comment: I'm not sure how the decibel values come into play here? @TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: All filters ought to be defined by dB in passband @ f1,f2 and bandstop @ f3,f4  also consider phase shift , amplitude ripple. It needs to be high order and TI.com has excellent tools.

Comment: Your filter is poorly defined and so it will respond the same.

Comment: As an aside a square wave has odd harmonics of the fundamental so a 6 kHz square wave has tones at 18 kHz, 30 kHz, ..., not ideal for characterizing a filter

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this and each have their merits

1. Simulink.
   The most visually intuitive method to perform what you are requesting
2. Matlab script using ft, gensig & lsim

   H = tf([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9hTL.png),[1e-3 1]);
   [sig,t] =  = gensig('square',10e-3,50e-3,1e-6);
   lsim(H,sig,t);

[image]

Comment: I'm currently looking at the gensig documentation which seems to be what I need to use. But how do I set the frequency of the wave? Because I noticed that you set your period as 1ms, your duration as 0.05ms and sampling as 1ns. Why did you choose these values? @JonRB

Comment: Ideally my period should be 1/f where f is the frequency of the specified wave I am trying to create. @JonRB

Comment: I set the frequency by the period. Period = 1/f.  I set the period to be 10ms so the 1/2 period would be 5ms so a transfer function with a 1ms time constant would be at 5 time constant. I set 50ms so I would have 5 complete cycles and 1us (not 1ns) so the fidelity was enough for a plot. Basically all for visual example NOT anyone specific case